# Connecting Node.js script to a front-end project

Tags: javascript, node.js

As a javascript newbie, I want to create a front-end project with a very little backend solution using Node.js.

I have a user inteface with some variables and a button. These variables have to be passed to a simple .txt file(on my filesystem) and overwrite its content. For this, I'm using a nodejs script:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('log.txt', 'This is my text', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Replaced!');
});
```

But I want this to work onClick, whereas this only works from the command-line.

So I have the two following problems:

1. I want to update the .txt file with the button click. So basically the above written code has to be executed, when I click the button. But I don't understand, how to connect the front-end with this nodejs file.
2. I want the content to be dynamical. I'm sure, once the first problem is solved, this will be straightforward, but right now I don't know this either.

I'm 100% sure I'm missing something(maybe a web-server, but even then, how?). I did my research but all I found was either an overkill or I didn't even understand it. Any help would be appreciated, a tutorial, an advice or just a keyword, that I can use for my research.

Comment: Node.js is a web server platform. I'm a newbie myself. I found this tutorial very helpful. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial.

Comment: I think that your file should be server-side and your node script included in a small API (you can easily find documentation about Node API). When an action is performed client-side, use Ajax to request your API with proper params, update your file and send its updated content to you client-side to update your user interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [express](https://expressjs.com). It's a "Fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework for node". With this you can build a small webserver:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000); // Webserver is running on port 3000
```

If you run it and go to your browser on `http://localhost:3000`, it would print `Hello World`.

Now what you would do is call your logging function every time a specific URL is requested.

```
var fs = require('fs');

function log(text, callback) {
  fs.writeFile('log.txt', text, callback);
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  log('This is my text', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send('Replaced!');
  });
});
```

Now when you click the button you need to make an AJAX request to the server (maybe using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)).

Comment: Okay, now I'm a bit further. I have played around with Express and Node since then and looked up a couple of youtube tutorials. I have one remaining question though. So if I want my app to have a server(or build any real life web application) I have to say goodbye to the conventional html and css and use preprocessors instead of them?

Comment: Not at all, but they certainly make life easier for you. You can serve your website from a standard webserver and make the AJAX requests to a different server.

Comment: But then again where is the connection between the front-end and the back-end? Can I state AJAX request to the express server from the front-end? By the way, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Given your frontend is hosted on example.com and your backend on api.example.com. On your frontend you can then make requests to api.example.com.

Answer (score 3):

Node.js doesnt have a built in front-library like some other scripting languages such as Python or VB. To create a node.js your intuition was correct in that you will need your app to expose itself as a web-server.
The popular library to do this is called express and it is very easy to get started. 
I suggest that you follow the [express quickstart tutorial](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to get into it.

From here you can wrap your code inside a route of the webserver (say `/save`) for example

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/save', function (req, res) {
  fs.writeFile('log.txt', 'This is my text', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Replaced!');
    res.send('Replaced!')
  });
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

With this example with the dependencies installed opening localhost:3000/save in your browser would cause your code to be run.